# How to create a pivot table to show the number of shared values between values on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Assume I have the following table:

```
id    test
A    test_1
B    test_1
A    test_2
C    test_3
D    test_4
```

How can I create a pivot table to show the number of similar ids between each two tests. Such as below:

```
          test_1    test_2    test_3    test_4
test_1      2         1    
test_2                1
test_3                           1
test_4                                      1
```

Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Shouldn't either of those columns or rows have the values A-D?

Comment: I am stuck on how to approach this problem. No, I just need to count the number of distinct ids for each (test)column/test(row) combination as in the second table

Comment: So how does `test_1` relate to `test_2`?

Comment: id 'A' is duplicated for test_1 and test_2. This is how they are related. (row 1 and 3)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would create the table in a *different* format, one row for each pair that exists:

```
select t1.test, t2.test, count(t2.id)
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.test = t2.test
group by t1.id, t2.id;
```

You can pivot this by doing:

```
select t1.test,
       sum(case when t2.test = 'test_1' then 1 else 0 end) as test_1,
       sum(case when t2.test = 'test_2' then 1 else 0 end) as test_2,
       sum(case when t2.test = 'test_4' then 1 else 0 end) as test_3,
       sum(case when t2.test = 'test_4' then 1 else 0 end) as test_4
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id= t2.id
group by t1.test;
```